# Remap cPanel Default Directory for Storing Files

Tags: linux, storage, web-hosting, cpanel, whm

I am looking at Digital Ocean's [block storage](https://www.digitalocean.com/features/storage/) as a potential way to scale a web server running cPanel's storage of all the public web content uploaded by users. After formatting and mapping the drive to the server, is there a configuration option in cPanel/WHM that allows you to remap the default location for new accounts? I realize each new user gets a home directory so would would a symbolic link be the answer instead? Just trying to figure out the best way to map and use the mapped storage instead of the default server storage.

Comment: You can modify /home/user or /home/user/public_html using files for user data, templates ... such /var/cpanel/userdata/USERNAME/DOMAIN.COM... https://www.servint.net/university/article/the-tech-bench-changing-a-document-root-in-cpanel/

Comment: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/file-management/changing-the-document-root-with-root-access

Answer (score -1):

This sort of answers the question:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1951526

Comment: This link not about question. Question it's about Cpanel. Cpanel it's a hosting control cpanel, with specials requeriments, and not installable on Debian flavours.